# Topology in $\mathbb{R}$: neighborhood basis and check if it is a first-countable space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to obtain a neighbourhood basis of the following topology:
$T=\{\emptyset\} \cup \{A \subseteq \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{N} \subseteq A\}$

I have thought of the following basis $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: B(x)=\{V \subset \mathbb{R}|x \in V \, \,\text{and}  \, \,\mathbb{N} \subset V\}$, which would not verify the first-countable axiom. Could someone tell me if I am right? Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x \in \mathbb R$ we can argue that $\{\{x\} \cup \mathbb N\}$ is a neighberhood basis of $x$.

First $\{x\} \cup \mathbb N$ is open from the defenition of the topology.

Now let $V \in T$ be an open set containing $x$. Thus $x \in V$ and from the defenition of the topology $\mathbb N \subseteq V$ and thus $\{x\} \cup \mathbb N \subseteq V$.

Thus $\{\{x\} \cup \mathbb N\}$ is a neighberhood basis of $x$ and of course it is countable and thus we have that this topological space is  first countable

Comment: I see it! Thank you very much!